# Cypress conditional button click

Tags: cypress, cypress-conditional-testing

I want to do a conditional testing in cypress. The situation is, that I want to achieve this:

If an alert modal window is present on the page , then click the YES button, otherwise do nothing.

The structure of the alert is something like:

```
<div class="swal2-container">
<h2>You are about to leave this page</h2>
<button type="button" class="swal2-confirm">Yes</button>
</div>
```

I tried it this way:

```
cy.get('body').then((body) => {
        if (body.find('button.swal2-confirm').length > 0) {
            cy.get('button.swal2-confirm').contains('Yes').click();
        }
    });
```

but this does nothing, it doesn't click the button. In test runner I just see as an output `get  ... body` and it is skipped.

i also tried to replace `body` with `$body` with no luck.

Comment: When you are searching for the Yes button, Is the action that was suppose to produce that modal, has it completely executed? To debug this behaviour apply a `cy.wait(4000)` before your code and do the action that produces the modal window window. Your code looks correct.

Comment: yes, the alert is there, I see it in test runner. It just doesn't click on the button so the alert stays there and then the next step fails, because the alert is still there

Comment: can you add the html screenshot of the element to the question?

Comment: wait man, I applied your advice and added cy.wait, and now it works! Strange, because in test runner I see that alert, but maybe it had a little time to click. Seems it is solved now, thank you for your advice, helpful as always

Answer (score 4):

It's a little more code, but a recursive function allows you to exit without failure (the do-nothing part).

You may need to adjust the number of attempts and the wait(200). Essentially the smaller the wait, the more attempts you may need.

At 20 attempts & 200ms wait, it's equivalent to `{ timeout: 4000 }` on a Cypress command.

```js
function ifModal(attempt = 0) {

  if (attempt > 20) return;  // do nothing

  if (Cypress.$('button.swal2-confirm').length > 0) {

    cy.contains('button.swal2-confirm', 'Yes').click();
    return;                 // done

  } else {

    cy.wait(200).then(() => {  
      ifModal(++attempt)      // next attempt
    })

  }
});  

ifModal();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the below code. `.includes()` is a jQuery function and I'm using it here for having text in the body.

```
cy.get('body').then(($body) => { 
     if ($body.includes('You are about to leave this page')) { 
          cy.get('button.swal2-confirm').contains('Yes').click(); 
     } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic function, inspired from Fody.

```
// !! Add the command
Cypress.Commands.add('redoCommandUntilConditionIsMet', ({
  condition,
  command, 
  maxAttempts = 20, 
  waitBeforeRetry = 1_000,
  waitForCondition = 200,
}) => {
    const redoCommandUntilConditionIsMet = (attempt = 0) => {
      if (attempt > maxAttempts) {
        return;
      }

      cy.wait(waitForCondition);

      if (condition()) {
        return;
      }

      command();

      cy.wait(waitBeforeRetry).then(() => redoCommandUntilConditionIsMet(++attempt));
    };
    redoCommandUntilConditionIsMet();
  }
});
```

And then can just do and can be re-used whenever required:

```
cy.redoCommandUntilConditionIsMet({
  condition: () => Cypress.$('button.swal2-confirm').length === 0,
  command: () => cy.contains('button.swal2-confirm', 'Yes').click(),
});
```

Comment: Looks like by adding the generic stuff you got the logic backwards, or sideways, because clicking the button isn't supposed to be in the retry branch.

Comment: And the wait is in the wrong place.